Diffrence between gguf and lora
Does the gguf format perform model quantization even though it's already quantized with LORA?
Hello ! im new to Llms ,and l've fine-tuned the CODELLAMA model on kaggle using LORA.I've merged and pushed it to  hugging face.I want to know if the model is already quantized with LORA why we need to requantized with gguf .

Model quantization and LoRA are different concepts.
As you know, LoRA is a kind of Parameter-Efficient Fine-Tuning technique which reduces the number of trainable parameters.
Whereas, model quantization reduces the size of a model by converting model weights from higher-precision representation(like FP32) to lower-precision representations(like bfloat16 or INT8).

"Thanks, Jaewo Kim. I'm a little bit confused about what happens when we load a model with load_in_4bit=True and torch_dtype=torch.float16 in this code:
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    base_model,
    load_in_4bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto")

Does it not quantize the model?"

@Samar Yes, it quantizes the model. And there is a possibility that what you use is a technique called QLoRA. In your case, QLoRA quantizes the pre-trained model itself to 4bit, and then applies LoRA. Here is the original paper which introduced QLoRA. http://arxiv.org/abs/2305.14314

@Samar http://huggingface.co/blog/4bit-transformers-bitsandbytes
